# Best way to Deploy smart contracts without Infura

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, infura, truffle-contract, truffle-deployment

I'm wondering what will be the best way to deploy our smart contracts. If i use Infura API, they are only serving 100 thousand requests per day.Due to that our team lost a client while performing a demo, the requests have been exhausted exactly while performing client demo. And also i came across Truffle-teams and I don't know how to use it. If you got any tutorials, lease share them!!.If is there any other ways to deploy our contracts to the public networks also mention them..

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: This is multiple questions in one an very hard to parse what's the question you are asking. I suggest trying to ask only a single question per a post here and try to adhere to the technical oriented format.

Comment: Just wanna know how to deploy our smart contracts to the public network without using infura API

Comment: You can run your own Ethereum node or pick one of these: https://ethereumnodes.com/

Comment: I don't want the API that work on requests/day basis..  But thanks for let me knowing other options too!!!